# App hangs on futex_wait_queue_me() every a couple of minutes

Tags: java, ubuntu, groovy

I am running a simple script in Groovy on an Ubuntu 11.10 machine, which takes key/value pairs and adds them to a JDBM map in a loop.
 Every ~3 minutes the script hangs for a couple of minutes and then resumes.
 When I look at the resource monitor I see that there is no CPU or Memory activity and the process is in `futex_wait_queue_me()`.
 
Please suggest means to overcome this, on a Windows machine by the way the application runs without the hangs.
Could this be an OS issue? (found many similar threads about similar `futex_wait_queue_me()` problems in Ubuntu0 
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a full thread dump of the waiting threads e.g. using jstack ? (You can remove the ones which are not)  I suspect you are getting a lower level dump and seeing there are sleeping threads which normal. These are usually ignored. Can you run the program with `-verbosegc` ?

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the quick reply, just to be sure that I follow you correctly you mean to add "-verbosegc" to the java command right? How to supply the thread dump, a screenshot of the resource monitor?

Comment: You add `-verbosegc` to the command line of `java`. It is possible if you are running low on memory for a GC to take minutes instead of a fraction of a second.  To get a stack dump, use `jstack` and ignore/delete all the sleeping threads. If you don't know what sleeping threads look like, take a stack dump when the program is behaving normally and only show the threads which are different. Once you have narrowed down one or two threads which are different you can post the text of them into your question as a code block.

Comment: OK, doing it, might take some time. By the way I dont know what GC is, but regarding memory I am using 16GiB ram and its only 10.3% used.

Comment: The GC is the garbage collector.  The default maximum size of heap is 25% of the memory so if your not using 25% the program isn't even using its maximum size.  One cause of unexplained long pauses in Java 6 is trying to lookup the IP addresses of hostnames incorrectly configured in DNS. That should be less of a problem in the lastest updates. I only mention it in case its means something to you.

Comment: Peter you were right it was a problem with the GC, I set the heap size to a huge number (<16GB) and it worked. I would of rather find a way to spread the GC activity over time, and trying playing with the different parameters but it looks to complex. Thank you anyway for your help

Comment: The solution is not so complex, discard less objects.  Depending on the application, you can reduce it to less than once per day (even monior collections)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone interested I used those parameters when running java:

```
-Xms16384M -Xmx16384M
```

You can find additional GC optimization tips at http://randomlyrr.blogspot.it/2012/03/java-tuning-in-nutshell-part-1.html

Answer (score 6):

Please check the version of the kernel. I ran into a similar problem (java and other multithreaded applications) on Centos6 and upgrading the kernel to version 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 solved the issue.

See the centos bug report: https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=8703 which contains this pointer to an explanation of the problem:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/76835b0ebf8a7fe85beb03c75121419a7dec52f0 [^]

My stacktrace was:

```
cat /proc/23199/stack
[<ffffffff810b226a>] futex_wait_queue_me+0xba/0xf0
[<ffffffff810b33a0>] futex_wait+0x1c0/0x310
[<ffffffff810b4c91>] do_futex+0x121/0xae0
[<ffffffff810b56cb>] sys_futex+0x7b/0x170
[<ffffffff8100b072>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: This should be marked as the actual answer @user971956.

Comment: this is the actual answer.